# Most recent count of records per policy with joins

Tags: sql, join, count, max

I have three tables I need to join and query a count of the total records per policy, but only the display the count that corresponds to the most recent run date. I've gotten close but my count keeps totally all run dates instead of selecting the most recent using max() alike I would expect. I've been racking my brain and tried several different methods. Any assistance it greatly appreciated. My apologies for all the hyperlinks to the screenshots. I'm new to the forum and I'm not sure how else to format the table data and the returns.

Here is my my initial starting point:

```
SELECT
d.max(r.RunDate),
p.PolicyName,
COUNT(r.UID_Records)
FROM Policy p
INNER JOIN Records r ON p.UID_Policy = r.UID_Policy
LEFT JOIN RunDate d ON d.UID_RunDate = r.UID_RunDate 
      AND d.ProcessedOn = 
        (
           SELECT MAX(ProcessedOn) 
           FROM RunDate x 
           WHERE x.UID_RunDate = d.UID_RunDate
        )
GROUP BY p.PolicyName
```

[Table1: RunDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj3eb.png)

[Table2: Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jneoU.png)

[Table3: Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzORC.png)

This is my result using the query above:

[My Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFj4r.png)

This is what I'm trying to return:

[Preferred Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bhpU.png)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Rank() function which will rank the policy based on the most recent date. I didn't build your schemas entirely or run your query but did this quick mock up of the schema and ran the below query: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ac77344403c841c64026fb43e3f7950)
This should help in achieving your final output.

```
SELECT
  date,
  policy,
  RANK() OVER (
    ORDER BY
        date desc
 ) AS rnk
FROM table

Results from this query:
9/16/20|policy3|1
9/13/20|Policy1|2
7/2/20|policy2|3
```

Comment: The only actual answer in this post is "try using a rank function". And it's not a good one. Links to other resources aren't answers, they're just supplemental. Put what yoiu need to answer or ask in the post, not just at a link. [answer] [ask] [help] PS If you do give a link or image, use the editing functions. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Help on formatting the link would be great - I tried following the example but it didn't convert it. Thanks.

Comment: Read the edit help re options on typing formatted links by hand, also re clicking on icons. Best to use sqlfiddle.com or dbfiddle.uk for SQL as they are less intrusive to visitors. But: "Put what you need to answer or ask in the post, not just at a link." That means everything. Use links only for what is supplementary. See my comments on the question post. PS The question if pinned down is (clearly) going to be an easily found duplicate, so shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @philipxy I've edited my response to use dbfiddle.uk and converted it to a link